# How to set or not set audio selector in AWS media convert?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

I got this error, when creating job for AWS media convert:

> Invalid selector_sequence_id [0] specified for audio_description [1].

I do not even need sound for my output mp4 video.

My intention is to loop for 2 second an image (png or jpg) and add a fade effect for the first frames.

How would you change the sent json?

```json
{
    "middlewareStack": {},
    "input": {
        "Queue": "arn:aws:mediaconvert:eu-central-1:634617701827:queues/Default",
        "UserMetadata": {},
        "Role": "arn:aws:iam::634617701827:role/service-role/MediaConvert_Default_Role",
        "Settings": {
            "TimecodeConfig": {
                "Anchor": "00:00:00:00",
                "Source": "EMBEDDED"
            },
            "OutputGroups": [
                {
                    "Name": "File Group",
                    "Outputs": [
                        {
                            "Preset": "createPromoVideo",
                            "Extension": "mp4",
                            "NameModifier": "_fade",
                            "VideoDescription": {
                                "CodecSettings": {
                                    "FilterGraph": "fade=out:150:30"
                                },
                                "ScalingBehavior": "DEFAULT",
                                "TimecodeInsertion": "DISABLED",
                                "AntiAlias": "ENABLED",
                                "Sharpness": 50,
                                "Height": 1080,
                                "Width": 1080
                            },
                            "AudioDescriptions": [
                                {
                                    "AudioSelector": {
                                        "SelectorSettings": [
                                            {
                                                "AudioSelectorName": "Default"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "CodecSettings": {
                                        "Codec": "AAC",
                                        "AacSettings": {
                                            "Bitrate": 96000,
                                            "CodingMode": "CODING_MODE_2_0",
                                            "SampleRate": 48000
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "OutputGroupSettings": {
                        "Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
                        "FileGroupSettings": {
                            "Destination": "s3://t44-post-cover/8fui.mp4",
                            "DestinationSettings": {
                                "S3Settings": {
                                    "AccessControl": {
                                        "CannedAcl": "PUBLIC_READ"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "Inputs": [
                {
                    "FileInput": "s3://t44-post-cover/8fui",
                    "VideoSelector": {
                        "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW"
                    },
                    "FilterEnable": "AUTO",
                    "TimecodeSource": "ZEROBASED",
                    "InputClippings": [
                        {
                            "StartTimecode": "00:00:00:00",
                            "EndTimecode": "00:00:02:00"
                        }
                    ],
                    "FilterGraph": "fade=in:0:30",
                    "AudioSelectors": {
                        "Default": {
                            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "AccelerationSettings": {
            "Mode": "DISABLED"
        },
        "StatusUpdateInterval": "SECONDS_60",
        "Priority": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS MediaConvert requires you to have at least one Audio Selector.

Just provide it with this simple one:

```
"Inputs": [
    ...
    {
        "AudioSelectors": {
            "Audio Selector 1": {
            "Offset": 0,
            "DefaultSelection": "DEFAULT",
            "SelectorType": "LANGUAGE_CODE",
            "ProgramSelection": 1,
            "LanguageCode": "ENM"
        }
    },
    ...
},
```

UPDATE:

A more barebones one:

```
"Inputs": [
    ...
    {
        "AudioSelectors": {
            "Audio Selector 1": {
                DefaultSelection: 'DEFAULT',
            },
        }
    },
    ...
},
```

Comment: I tried this already, did not help. I also added `AudioDescriptions` to `Outputs`, both has refrence called 'default`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the black video generator feature to make the background of the clip, and specify one or more image overlays on the output group.

For a 15 sec clip with fades, your job's 'Settings' stanza should resemble:

```
"Settings": {
"TimecodeConfig": {
  "Source": "ZEROBASED"
},
"OutputGroups": [
  {
    "CustomName": "out1",
    "Name": "File Group",
    "Outputs": [
      {
        "ContainerSettings": {
          "Container": "MP4",
          "Mp4Settings": {}
        },
        "VideoDescription": {
          "Width": 1920,
          "Height": 1080,
          "VideoPreprocessors": {
            "ImageInserter": {
              "InsertableImages": [
                {
                  "Width": 1920,
                  "Height": 1080,
                  "ImageX": 0,
                  "ImageY": 0,
                  "Duration": 15000,
                  "FadeIn": 200,
                  "Layer": 1,
                  "ImageInserterInput": "s3://BUCKET/img/TV-test-patternPNG.png",
                  "StartTime": "00:00:00:00",
                  "FadeOut": 200,
                  "Opacity": 100
                }
              ]
            },
            "TimecodeBurnin": {
              "FontSize": 16,
              "Position": "BOTTOM_CENTER",
              "Prefix": "TC"
            }
          },
          "CodecSettings": {
            "Codec": "H_264",
            "H264Settings": {
              "FramerateDenominator": 1,
              "Bitrate": 1000000,
              "FramerateControl": "SPECIFIED",
              "RateControlMode": "CBR",
              "FramerateNumerator": 60
            }
          }
        },
        "NameModifier": "out1"
      }
    ],
    "OutputGroupSettings": {
      "Type": "FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS",
      "FileGroupSettings": {
        "Destination": "s3://BUCKET/test/"
      }
    }
  }
],
"Inputs": [
  {
    "VideoSelector": {},
    "VideoGenerator": {
      "Duration": 15000
    }
  }
]
```

}

You can copy & paste this JSON into one of your previous job files to create a new job file close to what you want.